# How to display values in tamil font in FPDF

Tags: php, printing, fonts, fpdf, tamil

How to display values in tamil font in FPDF?

I have use this way, but not displayed.

```
$this->AddFont('TSCu_SaiIndira','','TSCu_SaiIndira.php');

$fontName = 'TSCu_SaiIndira';

$this->SetFont($fontName,'',10);
$this->Cell($this->field_width[$col],5,$value['regional_name'], 0, 0,
$this->field_position[$col]);
```

Answer (score 0):

please change your font `Geethapria.ttf` file it will display for Tamil font only